# Don't kill the child process after SBT is killed in Scala?

Tags: linux, scala, playframework, sbt, nohup

I am running a script in Scala and Play using:

`val pb = Process(s"bash $path/script.sh")
pb.run`

The script starts a background process in the background that is supposed to start run even when sbt is killed. Here is the script:

`#!/bin/bash
nohup liquidsoap liquidsoap.ls  >/dev/null 2>&1  &
echo $! > liquidsoap.pid`

The problem is that even after using nohup and redirecting the output. When I kill SBT, the background process that was started using the script is killed too.

Thank you

Comment: Try to run this script in xterm and close xterm after that. I suppose the process will be killed as in the sbt case case. That is not sbt issue but system-wide behaviour. I use screen utility to run background tasks

Comment: I already tried that. The process keeps running after I close xterm.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to you sbt file:

```
fork in run := true
```

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The problem was that when I was killing SBT I was sending a `SIGINT` signal to all processes. In order to avoid the created processes to not be killed I need to put the process in a different process group which is done the `setsid` command.